# HTML Form Not Posting Data to File

Tags: php, apache2

So, my page loads fine, and it loads the formsubmit.php page, but it is not posting the data to the file.

form.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>Enter Your Email</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
        <section class="loginform cf">
        <form name="login" method="post" action="formsubmit.php">
                <div class ="createaccount">
                        <ul>
                                <li class="subcolumn11">Company Email</li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
                <div id ="column2">
                        <ul>
                                <li>
                                        <input type="email" name="pemail" placeholder="firstname.lastname@peoplenet.com" >
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Email Submit">
                                </li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
        </form>
        </section>
</body>
</html>
```

formsubmit.php

```
<?php
file_put_contents('data.txt',trim($_POST['pemail'])."\n",FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

data.txt is in the same folder as both form.php and formsubmit.php but I cannot seem to get anything to actually append to this file.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

EDIT1:

print_r($_POST['pemail']; returns data (this case test@test.com)

I set the folder to chmod 777 and the individual file to chmod 666 and I still cannot get it to post to file.

EDIT2:  NVM it finally posted to the file. It just took 30 seconds for some reason.  It was a permission issue.

Comment: Check permisions for your .txt file

Comment: Do a print_r($_POST) ;

Comment: Use full path for. Txt file

Comment: print_r($_POST);  returns Array ( [pemail] => test@test.com ) 

I also changed the data.txt to the full absolute path.

Data.txt still only contains #Data as the first line, which I put there manually.

Comment: data.txt has rw-r--r-- rights and is owned by root, guessing it is a permissions issue.